# In a new unconnected battery, has a chemical reaction already occurred to cause excess electrons on anode end?

Tags: electricity, electric-circuits, batteries, electrochemistry

REACTION 1: When I buy a new unconnected alkaline cell, has a chemical reaction already occurred on anode end which releases electrons on anode end?

REACTION 2: Also, in the same new unconnected state of the battery, has a chemical reaction occurred at cathode end that captures electrons from cathode end?

After thinking this through I feel that while REACTION 1 happens in a new unconnected battery, the other REACTION 2 does not occur since there are no free electrons to be captured. If REACTION 2 also did occur in a unconnected new battery then the electrolyte would get all consumed and battery would die pretty soon when connected to an external circuit.

Answer (score 6):

Both reactions have taken place, but involving only an extremely limited number of electrons. At the cathode electrons have been captured from the cathode assembly, including the metal terminal. But relatively few electrons have been captured, and, indeed, relatively few have been released at the anode.

The reason why only relatively few (relative, that is, to the total number of free electrons in the anode and cathode assemblies) are involved is that those on the anode set up an electric field that opposes more electrons arriving and shuts down the reaction. Similarly the positive charge on the cathode assembly opposes more electrons being taken from the cathode assembly and shuts down the cathode reaction.

As you know, all this changes when you provide an external conducting path between cathode and anode: electrons can now escape from the anode assembly and travel through the conducting path to the cathode. So now the reaction at the anode can proceed and electrons are supplied to the cathode so the reaction at that electrode can proceed as well.

Comment: But on anode end there are no free electrons, so how come electrons can be captured in reducing the cathode material? Free electrons would only be available on cathode side when they flow from anode to cathode through a connected external circuit.

Comment: Electrons are liberated at the anode within the cell and deposited on the anode assembly. Electrons are taken from the cathode assembly to take part in the reaction at the cathode.

Comment: I read somewhere that in an alkaline battery, electrons cannot flow from anode to cathode due to a special material surrounding the electrolyte on anode end that allows ions to pass through but not electrons from anode. I was viewing a video on YouTube which is as at this link https://youtu.be/PXNKkcB0pI4

Comment: That's right; it's ions that travel within the electrolyte. [If I remember rightly, the literal meaning on 'ion' is *traveller*].

Comment: Lazy Reader asks - Can you guesstimate the fraction of all free electrons which constitute the "few"?  I would have guessed on the order of 1E-6 but not based on any actual calculations.

Comment: Wow! That's not easy! I think what I'd do is to take an electrode attached to a spherical conductor (radius ). That's because we know the capacitance! In equilibrium the charge (, say) will be just on the surface and we can equate the potential to the emf ℰ due to the reaction at the electrode. So $=4_0  ℰ$ and the number of electrons involved will be this divided by .  I make it in the order of $3\times 10^7$ for a 10 cm diameter sphere. But of course the fraction of the electrode assembly's free electrons that this represents will depend on the thickness of the metal.

Comment: @Philip Wood, The reaction on  cathode end is 2MnO2(s) + H2O(l) + 2e− → Mn2O3(s) + 2OH−(aq). Since electrons released on anode end by the reaction Zn(s) + 2OH−(aq) → ZnO(s) + H2O(l) + 2e− , cannot reach the anode when alkaline battery is unconnected due to the non-permeable layer between anode and electrolyte, so then where is cathode getting 2 electrons for the reaction on its end?

Comment: "so then where is cathode getting 2 electrons for the reaction on its end?" From the electrode assembly itself! That's why the electrode assembly gets a positive charge! But this very positive charge, when it gets large enough (which is in a small fraction of a second) stops more electrons leaving the electrode assembly to take part in the reaction. So the reaction stops.

Comment: The cathode material is a form of  Manganese oxide. From what you mentioned in your last comment,  the electrons come from this same material. Ok, that makes sense. I think this part wa not clearly understood from your answer.

Comment: "the electrons come from this same material. " and the terminal etc. that connects to the electrode material itself. That's why I kept writing "[electrode] assembly".

Comment: @Philip Wood, I posted another question on Chemistry forum and received a different answer.  It said the reaction on cathode end only occurs if there is a wired battery, i.e the other half of a redox chemical reaction happens in a battery only when it's connected to an external circuit. Redox reactions occur in pairs so electrons gained in one reaction are obtained by electrons lost in the other part of the redox reaction.

Comment: The Chemistry forum answer that you've reported is a very slight oversimplification. If you've understood my answer and comments you'll be able to see why this is so.

Comment: Bear in mind the experimental evidence: with a battery of cells in series you can actually *detect* the charges on the terminals. The only plausible way of explaining these charges is by electrons having been taken from the cathode terminal to take part in the (short-lived) cathode reaction, and electrons having been deposited on the anode terminal from the short-lived reaction at the anode.